# In Windows 7, can I see the "USB events" somewhere as they happen?

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a nasty case of some USB device constantly pluging and unplugin while VirtualBox, or Mumble, is running. The constant "bloop-bloop" noise is driving my mad. How do I find out which one it is? I can't even unplug them all physically, since some are used within the PC case. Turning the "USB sound" off doesn't really help as those constant events really slow down the whole PC.

Comment: is this happening with one particular  pen drive or all pen drives?

Comment: @tumchaaditya I don't know. This is the reason why I have to ask! I need a log to see which one it is.